# Cannot open pdf created by ITextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using ITextSharp for creating pdf in ASP.net, every thing works fine on my local machine, when I run it on IIS server, pdf is created successfully and can be open and view in the folder it is made, but I cannot open the pdf programmatically from C#. 
I am using `Process.Start(path)` to open the file.

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("TransferLetter/" + filenamee), FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();

DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
html = html.Replace("[Date]", Request["Date"] + "");
html = html.Replace("[Address]", Request["MailingAddress"].ToString());
html = html.Replace("[PlotNo]", Request["PlotNumber"].ToString());
html = html.Replace("[Block]", Request["Block"].ToString());
html = html.Replace("[Size]", Request["PlotSize"].ToString());


string pa = Server.MapPath("TransferLetter/" + filenamee);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pa);
```

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: Go to run command and give the exact path you are passing for Process.Start() and see if it works. Mostly file path is not correct.

Comment: Are you trying to open Acrobat Reader from inside IIS? Or from some other machine? Process.Start doesn't read anything. It executes commands or starts the registered program for the document you specify. It will only open a reader for a document if a reader is actually installed. In other words, have you installed Acrobat Reader on the machine where you run Process.Start?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi i have edited the code in my question. please check it.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi i checked it but problem is there, one thing the problem is on IIS. Not in local machine.

Comment: Just to be clear, on your local environment you browse to a web page, a PDF is created and then it opens, right? But on the server using the same steps the PDF doesn't open, right?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes you got my point. do you have any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This will never work this way. `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` runs on the server, not the client. When you're developing on your local machine you are **both** the *server* and the *client* so it appears to work but once you separate these two you get your failure.

To say that again but in a different way, you are asking the *server* to build your PDF and then you are instructing the server to launch its local copy of Adobe Reader and display the PDF to whoever is physically logged into the server at the moment. (Ok, not 100% true but pretty close.)

Instead you need to send the PDF to the client using something like `Response.Redirect()` or `Response.Write()`. Looking at your code you should be able to perform:

```
Response.Redirect("TransferLetter/" + filenamee)
```

Using iTextSharp you don't actually have to even write the PDF to disk. You could use a `MemoryStream` instead of a `FileStream`, call `MemoryStream.ToArray()` write before disposing of it and using `Response.Write()` on that byte array. If you are writing small PDFs and/or are planning on multiple people accessing this that might be the safer way.

Comment: Ya, your suggestion seems to be the best, I have heard the some thing like that from a friend, I will try this today. I hope this will work. And sorry I cannot vote up yet. :/

Answer (score 0):

you need to use  `~` `tilde` operator to specify the `current project` folder path

Try This:

```
string pa = Server.MapPath("~/TransferLetter/" + filenamee);
```